# How to know which usb port is associated to which root_hub?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, usb-modem, dmesg, lsusb

I have a requirement where I would like to connect many USB devices to the system using USB hubs. Currently, I have 2 20 ports USB hub with 40 USB devices connected this way. When I am trying to add more devices by adding another USB hub but I am hitting the limits of xHCI. Please note that both USB hub and USB devices are USB 2.0.

*> dmesg*

```
[33358.689138] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[33358.691346] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 64.
[33358.693245] usb 1-7-port5: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

According to my findings, Adding a PCIE card for more USB ports should solve the issue as it will add a new host controller. But I believe, currently, my motherboard itself has an unused host controller.

*> lsusb -t*

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 20000M/x2
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 95, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/7p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 98, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 79, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 79, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 79, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 81, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 81, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 81, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 10, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 10, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 96, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 73, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 73, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 73, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 127, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 127, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 127, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 42, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 42, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 42, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 18, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 18, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 18, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
            |__ Port 6: Dev 101, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 29, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 29, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 29, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 69, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 69, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 69, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 41, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 41, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 41, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 100, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 83, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 83, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 83, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 67, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 67, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 67, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 85, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 85, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 85, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 65, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 65, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 65, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 97, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 27, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 27, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 27, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 39, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 39, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 39, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 71, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 71, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 71, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
            |__ Port 7: Dev 103, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 77, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 77, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 77, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 8, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 8, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 75, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 75, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 75, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 99, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/7p, 480M
            |__ Port 7: Dev 108, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 117, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 117, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 117, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 119, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 119, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 119, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 36, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 36, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 36, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 105, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 43, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 43, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 43, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 55, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 55, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 55, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 31, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 31, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 31, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 102, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 53, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 53, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 53, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 109, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 109, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 109, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 111, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 111, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 111, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 14, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 14, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 14, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
            |__ Port 6: Dev 107, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 89, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 89, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 89, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 87, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 87, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 87, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 106, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 66, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 66, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 66, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 123, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 123, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 123, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 125, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 125, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 125, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 121, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 121, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 121, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 104, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 37, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 37, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 37, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 93, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 93, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 93, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 91, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 91, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 91, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
    |__ Port 13: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 4, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 5, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 6, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 7, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
```

*this one*

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 20000M/x2
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
```

If my assumption is correct, how can I access ports associated with `Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M`?

The motherboard also has 2 USB C ports. I tried to use them using C type extender I had lying around for my MacBook but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to test, as the extender has 2xHDMI, 1xETH, 1xAUX, 4xUSB 3.0, 1xUSB C and more..

I did this though and I again got the same error, but this time a hub got added to the root controller in question, but not to `Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M`

Here are all the logs after connecting that extender:
*> dmesg*

```
[34744.523932] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[34744.545939] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0817, bcdDevice= 4.73
[34744.545951] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[34744.545955] usb 2-5: Product: USB3.0 Hub             
[34744.545959] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[34744.551886] hub 2-5:1.0: USB hub found
[34744.552205] hub 2-5:1.0: 4 ports detected
[34744.671720] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 54 using xhci_hcd
[34744.821952] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2817, bcdDevice= 4.73
[34744.821964] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[34744.821968] usb 1-7: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
[34744.821972] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[34744.827068] hub 1-7:1.0: USB hub found
[34744.827418] hub 1-7:1.0: 5 ports detected
[34745.139969] usb 2-5.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[34745.161857] usb 2-5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0817, bcdDevice= 4.73
[34745.161870] usb 2-5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[34745.161875] usb 2-5.1: Product: USB3.0 Hub             
[34745.161878] usb 2-5.1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[34745.168740] hub 2-5.1:1.0: USB hub found
[34745.169074] hub 2-5.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[34745.256248] usb 2-5.4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[34745.285690] usb 2-5.4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0749, bcdDevice=15.39
[34745.285703] usb 2-5.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[34745.285708] usb 2-5.4: Product: USB3.0 Card Reader
[34745.285711] usb 2-5.4: Manufacturer: Generic
[34745.285714] usb 2-5.4: SerialNumber: 000000001539
[34745.300233] usb-storage 2-5.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[34745.300810] scsi host46: usb-storage 2-5.4:1.0
[34745.420338] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[34745.422924] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 64.
[34745.426402] usb 1-7-port1: couldn't allocate usb_device
[34745.428601] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[34745.431287] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 64.
[34745.434990] usb 1-7-port2: couldn't allocate usb_device
[34746.310845] scsi 46:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  MassStorageClass 1539 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[34746.312157] scsi 46:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic  MassStorageClass 1539 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[34746.312762] sd 46:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg41 type 0
[34746.313107] sd 46:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg42 type 0
[34746.516474] sd 46:0:0:0: [sdap] Media removed, stopped polling
[34746.720153] sd 46:0:0:1: [sdaq] Media removed, stopped polling
[34746.722839] sd 46:0:0:0: [sdap] Attached SCSI removable disk
[34746.727157] sd 46:0:0:1: [sdaq] Attached SCSI removable disk
[34749.455215] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[34749.458569] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 64.
[34749.460521] usb 1-7-port1: couldn't allocate usb_device
[34749.461979] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[34749.463156] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 64.
[34749.466159] usb 1-7-port2: couldn't allocate usb_device
[34749.469438] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[34749.471022] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 64.
[34749.472421] usb 1-7-port5: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

*> lsusb -t*

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 20000M/x2
    |__ Port 5: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 14, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 54, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
    ...
    ...
```

- Motherboard: ASUS ROG Strix Z590-E Gaming
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- HUB: UHPPOTE Sipolar Industrial Grade 20 Port Usb2.0 Hub
- USB Device: E3372H Modem

Summary:

1. Is it possible to add more USB devices to the existing motherboard?
2. Is that really an unused root_hub?
3. If it is then can we connect more USB devices to it?
4. How can I connect more USB devices to the system if it's possible?
5. If it is not possible to add to the existing system then what are other ways for getting more devices added? PCIE Card? Any recommendations?